# Should I use the openSUSE installer to encrypt /swap until ecryptfs is updated to work with systemd?

Tags: opensuse, swap, ecryptfs

I recently installed openSUSE 12.3. I didn't use any partition encryption in the installer. Immediately after the install was complete, I installed `ecryptfs-utils` and ran `ecryptfs-migrate-user -u my_user_name` as root in tty1. This was also successful.

I then tried to run `ecryptfs-setup-swap` to encrypt my install's swap space. That seemed to fail: I got an error message stating that `/etc/init.d/boot.crypto` does not exist. `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` had both been modified, but were not pointing to real drives (e.g., `/dev/mapper/cryptswap` didn't exist, even though it was mentioned in `/etc/fstab`).

I then found a statement at http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Encrypted_filesystems#SysV_Init_Scripts_.28obsolete.29 that openSUSE 12.3 did away with `/etc/init.d/boot.crypto` in favor of a `systemd` implementation.

I have two questions following this:

1) Will `ecryptfs` eventually be updated to accommodate this new `systemd` implementation?

2) In the mean time, would it work just as well to have the openSUSE installer encrypt the /swap partition?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I am the upstream maintainer of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).  While I won't develop systemd integration for eCryptfs myself, I would be delighted to accept well formed patches, branches, or merge proposals that add such support.  The upstream userspace code is maintained as a branch [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/files).
2. Yes, it should work just as well to let the OpenSUSE installer encrypt swap.

Comment: @ Dustin Kirkland, thank you for your help! I would be interested to contribute, but don't have the technical prowess yet. As time goes on, I will definitely keep this in mind as a project!